# Icecast Streaming using Winform compressing wave buffer into MP3

Tags: c#, mp3, audio-streaming, naudio, icecast

I am building this desktop application that is based on windows forms c# the goal is for it to capture sound from the sound card and stream it to an Icecast server.
Now for the streaming part I am using [this](https://github.com/Zerpico/libShout-csharp) project it is based on a LibShout Library that was wrapped into C#. The problem that I am facing is that the streaming service that I am using only supports MP3 or AAC and for the recording I am using NAudio Library that provides a .wav buffer so when I inject that buffer into the icecast.send(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded); method I receive nothing on the other end.

Does anyone now how to continously compress a buffer (not a file) into Mp3 or AAC?

Comment: You simply pipe that PCM data through a codec, and stream the output of that codec to the Icecast server.  Whichever codec you license will have its own API.  Alternatively, consider Opus which is free to use, and can easily be used with FFmpeg and all of the .NET abstractions for it.